# How to do multiple, in place seds for one original pattern search?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I am new to shell scripting and am attempting to solve a problem.

Basically, I need to find instances of a `REGEX` pattern in a text file, do some `sed` editing on each result, and then output the result in place to the original text file without disturbing any other original text.

The mental block I'm facing is that a) I need to do multiple pattern replacements in order to accomplish the final transformed result, so it can't be fit into a single call to sed, and b) if I grep out the results with a `REGEX` pattern, it gives me only the results that match that pattern. Ok great, so I go ahead and edit those to transform them into the final desired output, but I want to write this change exactly in place where it was in the text file. You can't `pipe` `grep` to `sed -i` because it doesn't reference the original file anymore, just the result set. Am I thinking about this in the wrong way or is there some command I'm just not aware of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can "grep" before applying commands with sed's facilities for addressing:

```
sed '/grep-like regex/ s/pattern to replace/replacement/' -i file
```

Where the "-i file" tells sed to edit "file" in place.

Multple commands can be given ans separated either through semicolons or through the command line with multiple "-e" options:

```
sed -e '/regex1/ s/pattern1/replacement/' -e '/regex2/ s/pattern2/replacement/'
sed '/regex1/ s/pattern1/replacement/; /regex2/ s/pattern2/replacement/'
```

If in the example above regex1 and regex2 are the same, you can also group the replacement commands into a single block, by using backets:

```
sed '/regex/ { s/pattern1/replacement/; s/pattern2/replacement/ }'
```

or for the sake of clarity:

```
sed '/regex/ {
        s/pattern1/replacement/
        s/pattern2/replacement/
    }'
```

You can also further filter the lines to apply the commands by nesting the /regexes/:

```
sed '/regex1/ {
        s/pattern1/replacement/
        /regex2/ s/pattern2/replacement/
    }'
```

So the second substitute command is executed only if regex1 and regex2 match.

Comment: I just implemented this and it appears to work correctly, only there's one issue: If I want to replace say all ] characters with ! in the result set, sed is actually working on the entire line, not the matched expression, and so I end up replacing ] on the same line that weren't in the result set. Is there a way to get sed to only find and replace the portion of the text that matched the search?

Comment: As far as I know you have two options: either you repeat the expression in the substitute command, or you use the hold space (an auxiliary buffer you can use). The former option is probably a lot easier (even though the substitute command can become more complex). The second option is a little difficult and requires a couple of steps. If you want I can help you with either one (or even both =) ), but since the difficulty depends on the regexp you're using, I think it would be easier if you could show something to give me an idea of what you're trying to do =)

Comment: Hmmm... when you say repeat the expression in the substitute command, do you mean repeat the original REGEX command in those s/pattern1/replacement/ and s/pattern1/replacement/ lines somehow? If I could do that, it might also solve the other issue I realized, which is that I need a backreference to some numbers in the original  search within one of the other replacements in order to paste the numbers in a different spot of the string. I'd prefer to go that route over half space, I'm just not sure exactly how the first solution you proposed would look in code. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for the first option you would repeat the regex "grep" pattern in the "s" commands, also allowing you to capture anything from the original match. An example could be '/my.*pattern/ s/my\(.*\)pattern/keep \1/', but this example is kind of useless =)

Answer (score 5):

`sed` can handle multiple replacements just fine: `sed 's/p1/r1/g; s/p2/r2/g'`

But if you want to edit a file, don't use a stream editor.  `sed` is the streaming version of `ed`.  If you want to edit a file, just use `ed`.

```
echo ',s/pattern/repl/g;,s/pattern2/repl2/g;w' | tr \; \\012 | ed -s file
```

Given your comment, I think you want to do a search and replace only on lines that match a certain pattern.  For example, to replace 'foo' with 'bar' on all lines that contain 'qux', you can do:

```
echo '/qux/s/foo/bar;w' | tr \; \\012 | ed -s file
```

Please note that I'm being somewhat facetious about using `ed`.  You can do exactly the same thing with sed:

```
sed '/qux/s/foo/bar' file
```

but `sed -i` is a travesty (it breaks hard links).

Comment: So I just want to make sure, the second pattern operates on the result of the first pattern, right?

Comment: No, both patterns are applied to all instances in the file, but the second one is applied after the first.  So perhaps the answer is "yes".  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I probably didn't get this across (apologies), but I want to find results in the file that match a pattern, and then further edit only those results using patterns. [Find everything in files that matches pattern X] - > [In the result set from that search, find and replace little things like characters to make the transformation on the result set] - > [Write those changes to the original location where the results were in the text file.] Is that a little clearer now?